# Connected host failed to respond (internal NAT address)

Tags: c#, web-services, certificate

I'm writing my first C# web application that connects to an XML based service.  It requires that I present a certificate and feed the XML stream.  It seems to authenticate properly but then it gives the following error:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 10.1.10.4:3128

The funny thing is that I'm not on a proxy or anything like that.  I'm connecting directly to the internet.  At one point I we did use a proxy that with internal NAT address.

So my question is: Does Visual Studio have some sort of default proxy setting that I need to change?  This IP is no longer used for anything, so I know that I don't need to use any proxy authentication code.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Uri requestURI = new Uri("*site omitted*");

            //Create the Request Object
            HttpWebRequest pageRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestURI);

            //After installing the cert on the server export a client cert to the working directory as Deluxe.cer
            string certFile = "*certificate omitted*";
            X509Certificate cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(certFile);

            //Pull in your Data, if it is from an external xml as below or create an xml string with variables if a dynamic post is required.
            string xmlPath = "*XML omitted*";
            System.Xml.XmlDocument passXML = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
            passXML.Load(xmlPath);

            //XML String with the data needed to pass
            string postData = passXML.OuterXml;

            //Set the Request Object parameters
            pageRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            pageRequest.Method = "POST";
            pageRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
            pageRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            pageRequest.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
            postData = "xml_data=" + Server.UrlEncode(postData);
            pageRequest.ContentLength = postData.Length;

            //Create the Post Stream Object
            System.IO.StreamWriter postStream = new System.IO.StreamWriter(pageRequest.GetRequestStream());

            //Write the data to the post stream
            postStream.Write(postData);
            postStream.Flush();
            postStream.Close();

            //Set the Response Object
            HttpWebResponse postResponse = (HttpWebResponse)pageRequest.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Many classes use the Internet Explorer proxy settings. How are you communicating with the webservice (can you show us code)? Can you check if the Internet Explorer proxy settings are set to that IP address?

Comment: I added some sample code, hopefully it will help.  The error occurs at line "...System.IO.StreamWriter postStream = new System.IO.StreamWriter(pageRequest..."  I don't know much about C#, so any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you're going to find out what's going on is to look at the network traffic with Fiddler or maybe Microsoft Network Monitor.